# Amount of related entries in specific timeframe (Spring JPA)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am implementing a simply Spring Boot APP.

I have a class *Test* which contains a List of *TestExecutions*. The TestExecution has a start and end time.

The goal is to have a Table in my App showing the Test name and the amount of execution in a specific time frame (will be set via filter from the user).

1. It was quite easy to show the total amount of TestExecution with a custom @Formula (see below). But I wasn't able to show the amount of TestExecution in a specific TimeFrame, as I don't know how to handle the parameterization.

**Test.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tTest")
public class Test
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cId")
    private Integer id;

    /* removed annotations to simplify */    
    List<TestExecution> testExecutions;

    @Formula("(select count(*) from tTestExecution o where o.cTestId = cId)")
    private Integer amountTestExecutions;
..
}
```

**TestExecution.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tTestExecution")
public class TestExecution
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cId")
    private Integer id;
..
    @Column(name = "cStartDate")
    private Long startDate;
    @Column(name = "cEndDate")
    private Long endDate;
...
}
```

2. My second problem is that when sorting by this count(*) parameter the app gets quite slow (altough I already work with server side paging), as it needs to execute the count for all rows to sort it. Are there better ways of achieving the goal of having the amount of testexecutions, without implementing counters?

Appreciate any feedback, Marco